# How to achieve high availability in case of network partition scenario of 4 node zookeeper cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We have 4 zookeeper node cluster, I have read the documentation and it was mentioned that more than N/2 nodes has to be available for the cluster to be up.
We have 4 zk cluster where 2 are in one DC and other 2 nodes are in different DC, If one DC goes down I cannot have more than half nodes available.

Even if I have 6 node cluster 3 in one DC and 3 in other DC, I still cannot have more than half nodes available.

How can I achieve high availability even if complete DC goes down?

Comment: Can I have below config to make it work 4 node cluster, ZK1 (1,2,3), ZK2 (1,2,4), ZK3(1,3,4), ZK4(2,3,4), this way i have 4 node cluster but in config i only have 3 nodes, so technically its a 3 node. can this work or it will have any issues.